# The difference between Thread.currentThread().getId() and Process.myTid() in Android

Tags: java, android, multithreading

As known

> `myTid() -` Returns the identifier of the calling thread, which be used with setThreadPriority(int, int).

But I found `Thread.currentThread().getId()` does not equal to `Process.myTid()`. So, my guess the former is a JVM edition thread id and the latter is Linux edition thread id.

Am I right? If so, why does java make its own thread id and not use Linux thread id?

UPDATE:

After further research and reading the source code of android, I have new realization:

`Process.myTid()` is a platform(OS) related operation, and so does `Process.setThreadPriority()`, in native level source of android, they all invoke a system call to realize the target.

But java is a platform independent language, java doesn't force the host os need a "tid" or a `getTid()` method, since another os may identify its thread by a string key(just a example, :)). Then java identify its thread with its own way, assign a unique thread id in java scope, if java provide a static api like `Process.setThreadPriority()`, then the java scope id definitely will be one parameter, but we needn't since we can do this by call a Thread object method `setPriority(int priority)`.

Any comment is welcome.

Updated:

The answers all is right. But fadden's comment make me more clear. Thank you all.

Comment: @EJP `Process.myPid()` returns the process id. `Process.myTid()` is something different.

Comment: Linux threads have a process ID (a/k/a thread group ID) and a thread ID.  Dalvik threads have an internal 16-bit thread ID, necessary because Dalvik wants a short thread identifier and can't assume the OS will provide it (see: Mac OS X).  java.lang.Thread has its own ID, which *could* be the same as one of the others, but isn't.  So... take your pick.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that there are two types of threads in a Java environment:

- **Native Thread:** which is managed by the hosted OS.
- **Java Thread:** which is managed by the JVM and is communicated with the native thread.

Answer (score 0):

`Thread.getId()` : `return id;`

where id is assigned:

`Thread.create` : `id = ++Thread.count`

so, `Process.myTid()` is 'System tid', and `Thread.getId()` is 'Java thread id'