# Android, what is the difference between two ways of getting current thread Id?

Tags: java, android

When I log the two below thread Ids, they are different.

```
long threadId = Thread.currentThread().getId();
long threadId2 = android.os.Process.myTid();
```

But from Android document, they are quite the same:

```
/**
* Returns the Thread of the caller, that is, the current Thread.
*/
public static native Thread currentThread();
```

So I assume the first line will returns the id of the caller thread.

then this

```
/**
     * Returns the identifier of the calling thread, which be used with
     * {@link #setThreadPriority(int, int)}.
     */
    public static final int myTid() {
        return Os.gettid();
    }
```

From the comment, it looks like it is also the id of the caller thread (although they use the word 'calling').

They are supposed the same, or am I missing anything? Thanks.

Comment: From the comments they look the same to me too

Answer (score 0):

ThreadId and Tid are different.

ThreadId is more like pid, while Tid is a bit more complicated.

[Correction:] ThreadId is *not* pid, it's actually the value of `++Thread.count`

See details here:
[Difference between pid and tid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4517301/difference-between-pid-and-tid)
and here:
[The difference between Thread.currentThread().getId() and Process.myTid() in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898321/the-difference-between-thread-currentthread-getid-and-process-mytid-in-and)

Comment: Tks for your answer, but in my question above, which var is Tid? Second?

Comment: Yes, `myTid()` returns Tid

Comment: Actually there is a more accurate answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898321/the-difference-between-thread-currentthread-getid-and-process-mytid-in-and. I'll update my answer because `getId()` is not a *real* pid.

Answer (score 0):

Thread.currentThread().getId() : Returns the identifier of the caller thread , that is, the current Thread. 
        android.os.Process.myTid(): Returns the identifier of the calling thread, which be used with setThreadPriority(int, int).
        Here 
        Set the priority of a thread, based on Linux priorities.

Parameters
        tid     The identifier of the thread/process to change.
        priority    A Linux priority level, from -20 for highest scheduling priority to 19 for lowest scheduling priority.

For further reference

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Process.html#myTid()