# HandlerThread's thread ID - android

Tags: java, android, linux, multithreading

While I was going through the source code of `andorid.os.HandlerThread` class, I found that `Process.myTid()` was being used as Thread ID.

I searched it a bit and found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33171734/android-process-mytid-vs-thread-currentthread-getid) helpful answer, now I understand what is `myTid` and what's the [difference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19898321/the-difference-between-thread-currentthread-getid-and-process-mytid-in-and) between `myTid` & `Thread.getId()`.

Here is my question;

> **WHY** we need to get the ID from `Process.myTid()`? Why **not** use `Thread.getId()`?

```
@Override
public void run() {
    mTid = Process.myTid();
    Looper.prepare();
    synchronized (this) {
        mLooper = Looper.myLooper();
        notifyAll();
    }
    Process.setThreadPriority(mPriority);
    onLooperPrepared();
    Looper.loop();
    mTid = -1;
}
```

Comment: What are you wanting to do with the ID?

Comment: Nothing. I just want to know.

Comment: Are you wanting to know some uses for each?

Comment: I have read the question. I don't think it's clear what you want to know from the question.

You have asked why use `Process.myTid()` instead of `Thread.getId()`. However, you cannot answer a use-related question without a use-case.

Comment: Yes. They have used it in `HandlerThread` class and I want to why do they need `myTid`. What was the reason behind it? Isn't it enough?

Comment: Still looking for answer.

Answer (score 0):

All your `Thread` runs in a single `Process` (your application may have more than 1 process). Every single threads runs inside default pool. It means if you create a custom `ThreadPool`s your thread ids may be same but they belongs to different pools but as every threads runs inside a `Process` so each thread will have its own unique id.

[Thread.getId()](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/lang/Thread.java#1702) is simply java static auto-increment long for each thread, (this thread ID may be reused).

[Process.getTid()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/Process.java#512) retunrs `Os.gettid()`.

Comment: If there are two processes and `Process.getTid()` returns unique ID with in a process. Isn't there any **possibility** of matching IDs? Why do I need to care about matching thread IDs in **two different processes**? What I think is, threads in each process run in isolation from other processes. If we need to share data between processes, we use some protocol but *caring about threads in another process doesn't make sense at all*. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: You don't need to care about threads in other process, as you said each process run in isolation from other, so you should't be worry about caring the threads of other process\

Comment: What about the first part?

Comment: Have a look at [Os.gettid()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/system/Os.html#gettid()) or Process.getTid()

Comment: I  have  seen that.  It only guarantees uniqueness with in a process.